# Restricting Dynamic Type Sizes In SwiftUI ( iOS 15 < )

Tags: swiftui

as of iOS 15 in SwiftUI there is a modifier in order to limit maximum or minimum content size

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/dynamictypesize(_:)/

which set limit for content size if user tries to change font size via accessibility by passing a range
is there any alternative solution for iOS 13 & 14 ?

Comment: Were you able to find and answer for this?

Comment: nah, eventually I handled it manually by checking current size

Answer (score 7):

It may be late, but I’ve faced the same problem before and created an extension.
You can use it like a dynamicTypeSize modifier.

https://gist.github.com/MMP0/2c1b581ad071c4279806ed5ad995a18a

```swift
// iOS 13 - 14
Text("sizeCategory")
    .sizeCategory(.large ... .extraExtraExtraLarge)

// iOS 15+
Text("dynamicTypeSize")
    .dynamicTypeSize(.large ... .xxxLarge)
```